# Deck of Cards Objects Java

Tags: java

For my APCS class, we have to create a deck of cards using the method they have given us, and then shuffle it and play a game with it. However, I can not seem to figure out the first step: creating the deck. This is the code they've given us:

```
/**
 * Creates a new <code>Deck</code> instance.<BR>
 * It pairs each element of ranks with each element of suits,
 * and produces one of the corresponding card.
 * @param ranks is an array containing all of the card ranks.
 * @param suits is an array containing all of the card suits.
 * @param values is an array containing all of the card point values.
 */
public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) {
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
        for (String suitString : suits) {
            cards.add(new Card(ranks[j], suitString, values[j]));
        }
    }
    size = cards.size();
    shuffle();
}
```

Here's the portion of the main method that is supposed to create the deck of cards. Included is a sample that they've given us that is, I assume, supposed to create 6 cards, jack, queen, and king, in the two suits they've specified - red and blue. However, even this creates duplicate cards.

```
    //String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};
    String[] ranks = {"jack", "queen", "king"};
    //String[] suits = {"spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"};
    String[] suits = {"blue", "red"};
    //int[] pointValues = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11};
    int[] pointValues = {11, 12, 13};
    Deck d = new Deck(ranks, suits, pointValues);
```

The non-commented stuff is what they've given us, the commented stuff is what I thought would work. However, when I try to run my code, it creates 148 Card objects instead of just 52. I can't seem to figure out why. Any help?

Comment: Please post your code for Card as well.

Comment: You say that you get duplicate cards from the code posted where you expected 6. How many do you get, which cards are duplicated, and when are they duplicated? (in the code you posted? in the shuffle method you left out? in your code that prints duplicates?)

Comment: The `Deck` constructor *looks* OK. I'd check other methods that touch `cards` - mostly the `shuffle` method (Why not just use `Collections.shuffle()`?), but others as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try your code and it's okay. It seems that you have a bug in another part

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ranks = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                "jack", "queen", "king", "ace" };
        String[] suits = { "spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts" };
        int[] pointValues = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11 };
        deck(ranks, suits, pointValues);
    }

    public static void deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) {
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (int j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
            for (String suitString : suits) {
                cards.add(new Card(ranks[j], suitString, values[j]));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(cards.size());
    }
}

class Card {

    String rank;
    String suit;
    int value;

    public Card(String rank, String suit, int value) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

It prints 52, that it's correct.

How are you shuffling the Deck ? You use Collections.shuffle(cards) or a custom method ?

Comment: Oh wow, you were right! We had to write a custom shuffle method in a previous assignment, and I had copied it over, but when I changed the variable names, for some reason, I forgot to add the part where it removed cards, so it was just adding more. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is transposed..

```
for (int j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
    for (String suitString : suits) {
        cards.add(new Card(ranks[j], suitString, values[j]));
    }
}
```

should be

```
for (String suitString : suits) {
  for (int j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
    cards.add(new Card(ranks[j], suitString, values[j]));
  }
}
```

I think you want to loop the suits first, then the cards within those suits.

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: can you set a breakpoint, and make sure that your `suits` and `ranks` is correct?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard because the program is supposed to create a deck of 52 cards.

Comment: @sircapsalot If we're being honest, I don't know what "setting a breakpoint" means. I feel confident that if I can get the initial red and blue code to create the appropriate 6 cards, I can work with it from there, but even then, the code that our teacher gave us is making 15 cards rather than 6.

Comment: no problem, nccows.. go ahead and do what @rajah9 stated and post more code in your question. namely, the `Card` and `Deck` classes.

Comment: -1. If you're creating every combination of rank and suit, then it doesn't matter if you go rank-by-rank or suit-by-suit first.